# What is the transfer function of this system y(n) =2y(n-1)?

Tags: transfer-function

What is the transfer function of this system y(n) =2y(n-1)? Here there is no input dependence.  If you give one output sample, all the future output samples are determined by multiplying with 2.

Comment: A transfer function describes the relation between an input and an output. Since there's no input, you have to clarify what you mean by a transfer function.

Comment: OK.  It was just a thought.  Got clarity now.  So that equation does not have a transfer function,  Thanks for the clarification!